# About primes and Euler's totient function.

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Is (the number of primes $< n$)   less than (the number of positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$)?

Comment: No - least counterexample is $n=6$.

Comment: $\pi(x)$ is [prime-counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) that tells you how many positive integers $\le x$ are prime.

Comment: It is not the "Euler's theta" but the Euler's totient (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function involved.

Comment: If I have read this correctly then if you change less than to less than or equal to then it will be trivially true? Any prime, $p$, less than n had $gcd(p,n)=1$ and so if we denote the set of integers than are less than $n$  as and reletively prime to $n$ then any prime p less than $n$ will be in $X$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\frac{\pi(n)}{n}\sim\frac{1}{\log n},\qquad \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\tag{1}$$
and since:
$$ \sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}\sim \log\log n \tag{2}$$
by [Mertens' second theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems), your claim holds for any $n$ big enough. Moreover, it is true that:
$$ \varphi(n)>\frac{n}{e^\gamma \log\log n+\frac{3}{\log\log n}}\tag{3} $$
for any $n>2$, so $\pi(n)<\varphi(n)$ for any $n>30$.

However, there are some counterexamples for small values of $n$, as already noticed by ghosts_in_the_code.

Comment: Is the √n × π(n) >  'totient'(n) ?

Comment: How did you get equation 3?

Comment: how did you get equation 3)?

Comment: @201044: it is a known inequality you can find on Wikipedia.

Comment: What article is it found in?  Is it in the articles about Merten's theorems?

Comment: Equation 3) implies (e^[gamma]) lnln(n) + 3/( lnln(n)) >  (sigma)(n)/n. If n is a counterexample to Robin's inequality (n > 5041)  then (sigma)(n) >  e^(gamma) (lnln(n)). (Forgive notation)

Answer (score 0):

No, the hypothesis is wrong. Please quote where you found it (unless you wrote it on your own).

Some counter-examples: 6,8,10,12

However, I think your hypothesis is true after a certain value of $n$. There may exist a natural number $k$ such that your statement is true for all $n>k$. Maybe you could ask how to find this $k$.

Comment: Is it true 'pi'(n) times 'pi'('square root of n) is > 'totient'(n)? Forgive poor notation.

Comment: Is it true π(n) π(√n) > 'phi'(n) ?

Comment: @201044 I'm only a school student; I don't know how such questions are solved (or the notation). I only answered because the counterexamples seems obvious.